# walker talk not found when deleting yield in test

Tags: jaseci

```
import {*} with './tesla_ai.jac';
import {*} with './graph.jac';
import {*} with './nodes.jac';

walker nothing {}

test "Testing Flow"
with graph::tesla_ai by walker::nothing{
    flows = file.load_json("master_test.json");
    
    for flow in flows {
        std.log("\n==== Testing flow: " + flow["test_name"] + " ====");

        for step in flow['flow'] {
            spawn here walker::talk(question = step["query"]);

            res = std.get_report();

            std.log("HERE >>> ", step["query"] , " ==== ", res[-1]);

            assert(res[-1] == step['response']);  

        }
        jaseci.walker_yield_delete("talk");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to delete the yield of walker talk after it goes through the flow but it throws this run error when i run the sentinel test.

```
{"success": false, "response": "Walker talk not found!"}
```

I am trying to delete the yield everytime it goes to a new flow so it does not keep track with the last response or entities.

[image]

Comment: why is this a `python` related question?

Comment: Yep, that's not [tag:python]

Comment: What language is that? It's not Python. Please [edit] and fix the tags. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and check out [ask].

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf this is the jac language that runs on jaseci, its a language that sits ontop of a python stack

Comment: we don't have a high reputation if you guys can create a tag called jaseci it would be nice so we don't have to tag the stack it was built on.

Comment: @Shawn Done, created the tag :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the `jaseci.walker_yield_list()` action call to check that there is indeed actually walkers yielded and only call `jaseci.walker_yield_delete("talk");` if its in the list.

Comment: I did ```walker_list`` and the walker was there I then follow up and did ```walker_yield_list``` but it was empty so it was unable to delete.

Comment: `walker_list` lists all of the walkers in the sentinel (bascially all the ones in the jac or ir file that was used in `sentinel register` or `sentinel set`) yielded walkers only represents the walkers that yielded directly from direct `walker run`, `walker execute`, etc calls. I understand there is still some discussion aournd if all arbitrary yielded walkers should be in that list.